# Can't get sessionId in SoapUI

Tags: magento-1, api, soap, soap-api-v2

I created a new user in System > Web Services > SOAP/XML-RPC - Users.

I created a new project in SoapUI.

Opened login > Request 1 and filled it in:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:loginParam>
         <username>test</username>
         <apiKey>test123</apiKey>
      </urn:loginParam>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
         <faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://local.test.dev/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://local.test.dev/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're running Magento in kind of VM (vagrant/vm). The problem here is the fact that Magento is trying to load WSDL by hitting itself.

Regarding that, if local.test.dev is not set in /etc/hosts of the linux box that you're using, then it is the reason why it fails to you. So, just SSH to that machine, and add `127.0.0.1   local.test.dev`, and it should be okay.

Comment: Now I got `<faultcode>2</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Access denied.</faultstring>`

Comment: FIxed access denied by creating a role.